# Keep mouse in window?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mouse

I run a dual monitor setup, and Skyrim only plays on the left monitor in fullscreen mode.

But when I'm playing, and my mouse goes too far to the right the cursor actually shows up outside Skyrim. And if I click, it actives the window on the right (thus minimizing Skyrim)

Why isn't the mouse staying bound inside Skyrim? Any fixes for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this.  http://www.snakebytestudios.com/blog.php?id=392
It worked for me.  It is cursorlock, and does what games refuse to in dual monitor setups.

Comment: +1 Brilliant. The linked `Cursor Lock` program on that URL Works like a charm. I installed it and followed the instructions exactly for the Skyrim-Steam version and problem is solved.